# Population structure and SNP's in Linkage Disequilibrium

Tags: dna, snp, recombination

I am reading about population structure and how you could as an example use plink to analyze a set of SNPs for individuals in a vcf file to identify a given population structure.

I know that LD can be influenced by inbreeding, selection and genetic drift amongst others.

But for a given population, where the individuals who are not inbred, couldn't Linkage Disequilibrium also be used to identify population strucutre for the individuals present within a vcf file.?

So my question is, when would you use independently associated SNPs? when would you use SNPs in LD? or would you always simply prune those SNPs who are in LD?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer hinges on a crucial distinction, which the difference between **linkage** and **linkage disequilibrium**.

- **linkage** (physical linkage) is a measure of closeness on a chromosome between two loci. You can measure it in [centiMorgans](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjjn-3IwJj-AhUjIX0KHflJAUwQFnoECBYQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genome.gov%2Fgenetics-glossary%2FCentimorgan&usg=AOvVaw07c_C-fKLsOHqR7pAKkhp5).
- **linkage disequilibrium** (LD) is when genetic variants at two loci show a pattern of statistical non-independence. You can measure it using a [correlation coefficient](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3282397/), or related statistics.

Linkage causes LD, but many other phenomena also cause LD, including (yes) common ancestry, selection, or even meiotic issues. There is no requirement that loci in LD be on the same chromosome.

To get at your question, yes, you could use LD to infer [population structure](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article-abstract/35/10/1786/5132693) or [selection](https://academic.oup.com/gbe/article/15/3/evad032/7055906) (examples linked), or other things.

Pruning SNPs in LD is used when you are making a strong assumption about the absence of LD. For example, [using many SNPs in LD can lead to inflated estimates of heritability](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4tuf8wZj-AhUyIn0KHTprCi0QFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC3135810%2F&usg=AOvVaw3Bf8E9QjQat3Rw-eyf4-eT). This is because SNPs in LD are not independent observations, most obviously in the case of physical linkage. There is no point in observing 2 SNPs that are right next to each other in QTL mapping, for instance.

You would not want to prune SNPs in LD when you are doing any kind of [haplotype-based inference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2291540/), as just one example.

LD is a signal like any other, the question is whether you are interested in the non-independence of SNPs, or assuming the independence of SNPs.